# OCaml: a function that returns function

Tags: ocaml

When a function returns a function as result, let's say:

```
let func = function
| pat -> (function | pat -> x
                   | b -> y)
```

the two `pat` are not the same thing, the second `pat` can match to anything, so the last line is never reached. Any hint on how to solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to express the second `pat` should be equal to the matched value against the first `pat` in your code, your code is wrong. It must be:

```
let func = function pat ->
  function 
    | pat' when pat = pat' -> x
    | b -> y
```

Pattern variables introduce new fresh variables and cannot refer to values bound to variables with the same name.

Answer (score -1):

You should not use pattern matching just to test equality. You should use `if then else`.
Your function is equivalent to:

```
let func a b if a = b then x else y
```

Using guards (the `when` part of camlspotter's answer) will work but is bad style (the caml compiler used to complain about it).

Comment: The only warning about guards I can remember concerns the case where all branches are guarded (because the compiler cannot decide whether the matching is exhaustive or not). This is still a warning in current versions, but this is not the case here (although I agree that in this very specific case `if then else` makes more sense than `match`).